# Representation of multiaffine functions.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $\mathbf{y},\mathbf{g}\in \mathbb{R}^n_+$, and let $M\left(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{g}\right)$ be real-valued and multiaffine in $\mathbf{g}$. In other words, for every $k\in \{ 1,...,n \}$, $M\left(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{g}\right)$ is affine in $g_{k}$, or
$$M\left(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{g}\right)=A\left(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{g}_{-k}\right)g_{k}+B\left(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{g}_{-k}\right)$$
for two functions $A$ and $B$.

I have read that, since it is multiaffine, $M$  has the following representation: for every $\mathbf{y}\gg0$, there is $\phi_{S}\left(\mathbf{y}\right)$ for every nonempty $S\subseteq\left\{ 1,...,n\right\}$, such that

$$M\left(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{g}\right)=\sum_{S}\phi_{S}\left(\mathbf{y}\right)\left[\prod_{j\in S}g_{j}\right].$$

Can you please give me an intuition of why this is the case? Also, is this true even if one of the $g_j$ is zero?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: both $A$ and $B$ in your decomposition are multi-affine, indeed
\begin{align*}
B(\mathbf y,\mathbf g_{-n})&=M(\mathbf y,\begin{bmatrix}g_1&\dots&g_{k-1}&0&g_{k+1}&\dots&g_n\end{bmatrix})\\
A(\mathbf y,\mathbf g_{-k})&=M(\mathbf y,\begin{bmatrix}g_1&\dots&g_{k-1}&1&g_{k+1}&\dots&g_n\end{bmatrix})-A(\mathbf y,\mathbf g_{-k})\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Using the fact that $A$ and $B$ are also multi-affine, we can show that it must be $A\left(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{g}_{-k}\right)=A\left(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{0}\right)$ right? If so, I get why the sum and the $\phi_S$ but why the product of $g_j$s?

Comment: nope, using the formula you have you, you can write $A(\mathbf y, \mathbf g_{-k})=A'(\mathbf y, \mathbf g_{-\{k,\ell\}})g_\ell + B'(\mathbf y, \mathbf g_{-\{k,\ell\}})$. You can therefore iterate until $\mathbf g$ is empty inside the $A, A', A''$ functions and is just expressed as factors. Another way to go from there is by induction, the two formula you provide match for $n=1$, then use the Hint for induction step.